# Was Picasso chased out of town after unveiling Guernica?

Tags: culture, art

In multiple interviews, Lana Wachowski has told this story:

> Picasso, when he revealed [Guernica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guernica_(Picasso)), was actually chased to the train station by an angry mob.
>
> —[The Wachowskis | DePaul VAS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARoKJ00cEZ8#t=25)

> But we knew, we knew just as the way Picasso was hunted and rocks were hurled at him when he first released or when he first unveiled Guernica, I mean he was like literally hounded by a mob out of the city.
>
> —[Andy & Lana Wachowski & Tom Tykwer Talk CLOUD ATLAS, SPEED RACER, Test Screenings, Deleted Scenes, Favorite Movies & More](https://collider.com/andy-wachowski-lana-wachowski-cloud-atlas-speed-racer-interview/)

Did this happen?

Comment: Your Wikipedia link says "At *Guernica*'s Paris Exhibition unveiling it garnered little attention." It seems unlikely Picasso would have been chased out of 1937 Paris.

Comment: Usually, even fake rumors have some internet buzz spreading them, but in this case I haven't been able to find any other source that mentions this.